# What's wrong with my std::copy operation?

Tags: c++, stl, copy

I have fixed length char array used to store my decoded data. Once finish decoding, I want to copy content of the char array to a char vector for later use. When debugging to the line of "std:copy(...)" an error occurred. What's wrong with my std::copy usage?

Thank you!

```
std::vector<char> m_cCalibrationID;
char cCalibrationID[5];
memcpy(cCalibrationID, pszData, 4);
cCalibrationID[4] = 0;

// Copy to vector
std::copy ( cCalibrationID, cCalibrationID + 4, m_cCalibrationID.begin() );
```

Comment: What error occurred? Did your computer catch fire? Did your compiler refuse to compile your program? Did your program terminate with a segmentation violation? Did you get incorrect results?

Comment: Sorry for my typing mistake! The vector variable should be m_cCalibrationID.

Comment: @GoldenLee: Don't type, instead, write a minimal test-case and copy+paste that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring that you named them the same thing and pretending you didn't, you need to allocate space for your vector first:

```
char arr[5];
memcpy(arr, pszData, 4);
arr[4] = 0;

std::vector<char> vec(5); // contains five usable elements
std::copy(arr, arr + 5, vec.begin());
//                 ^^^  should be + 5, not + 4, to get null terminator
```

Or you can use `std::back_inserter`:

```
char arr[5];
memcpy(arr, pszData, 4);
arr[4] = 0;

std::vector<char> vec; // contains zero usable elements
vec.reserve(5); // reserve space ahead of time
std::copy(arr, arr + 5, std::back_inserter(vec));
```

That will `push_back` each copied element. That said, why not skip the middleman?

```
std::vector<char> vec(5);
std::copy(pszData, pszData + 4, vec.begin());
// vec[4] already initialized to zero
```

Comment: Thank you very much GMan! I made a terrible mistake. I've already fixed my problem by using the following statementm_cCalibrationID = std::vector<char>(cCalibrationID, cCalibrationID + 4);

Comment: @GoldenLee: Heh, using the constructor slipped my mind. That's good.